# AWS-Lambda in python: Calls to dynamodb are successful in lambda handler function but not successful outside of lambda handler function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in python and a dynamodb. When I make a call to dynamodb from within lambda handler function this call is successful. But call to dynamodb outside of the lambda handler function is not successful and gives access denied exception.

Lets say I have a table "List" in dynamodb. I put an item in dynamodb within lambda handler function. Code works fine and an item is added in the DB.

```
#lambdaModule

import boto3
class LambdaFunction:
      def lambda_handler(self, event, context):     
           dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
           table = dynamodb.Table('List')
           table.put_item(
                           Item={
                                  'username': 'janedoe',
                                  'first_name': 'Jane',
                                  'last_name': 'Doe',
                                  'age': 25,
                                  'account_type': 'standard_user',
                                }
                           )
```

But when I try to add item in the db from outside of lambda it gives me access denied error.

```
import boto3
class LambdaFunction:
      def lambda_handler(self, event, context):     
           #Some logic

      #Accessing dynamodb from outside of lambda function.
      dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
           table = dynamodb.Table('List')
           table.put_item(
                           Item={
                                  'username': 'janedoe',
                                  'first_name': 'Jane',
                                  'last_name': 'Doe',
                                  'age': 25,
                                  'account_type': 'standard_user',
                                }
                           )
```

Above code give following access denied error

```
"[ERROR] VerboseClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) on request (BA2U74TQ90HACN013TMF2BGEENVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG) on table 
(dev02-up-svc-fss-stack-BlockLists-1DRNZPW6GRDV0) when calling the DescribeTable operation: Traceback (most recent call last):&nbsp;&nbsp;File \
"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return load_source(name, filename, file)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/la
ng/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;module = _load(spec)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line
 696, in _load&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 677, in _load_unlocked&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\",
 line 728, in exec_module&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/score.py\",
 line 179, in <module>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;class ScoreService(Service):&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/score.py\", line 180, in ScoreService&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
 ;&nbsp;ent = _name_dob_list.match(\"first_name\", \"last_name\", \"2000-12-12\")&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/lists.py\", line 449, in match&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 &nbsp;obj = BlockLists.match(self.name, attribs, self.params_meta)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/lists.py\", line 359, in match&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;params_a
 s_string)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/models.py\", line 485, in get&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hash_key, range_key = cls._serialize_keys(hash_key, range_k
 ey)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/models.py\", line 1372, in _serialize_keys&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hash_key = cls._hash_key_attribute().serialize(hash_k
 ey)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/models.py\", line 1219, in _hash_key_attribute&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hash_keyname = cls._get_meta_data().hash_keyname&n
 bsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/models.py\", line 1262, in _get_meta_data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cls._meta_table = MetaTable(cls._get_connection().describe_ta
 ble())&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/connection/table.py\", line 263, in describe_table&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return self.connection.describe_table(self.t
 able_name)&nbsp;&nbsp;File \"/var/task/pynamodb/connection/base.py\", line 659, in describe_table&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;tbl = self.get_meta_table(table_name, ref
```

I have given full access to db in template.yaml file.

```
LambdaFunction:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: lambdaModule.lambda_handler
        Events:
          ScoreEvent:
            Type: Api 
            Properties:
              Path: /score
              Method: POST
              RestApiId: !Ref FraudScoreAPI
        Policies:
          - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but my first instinct suggests that once you are outside of the handler you are no longer in the Lambda's execution context and any permissions granted (via your stack) will not be visible. My suggestion here is to make the insert logic a function and call the function from within the handler method.